# Using jQuery to go to show transitions with anchors

Tags: jquery

I am building a simple image fade transition and I've found a way to do it, but when I try to apply anchor tags to my images, the rotation stops and doesn't start again and then also does a blank image during rotation. I am barely understanding the jQuery on this and I think it has something to do with going to the next element and when I add an anchor, it sees that as next element and screws up. Can someone help me adjust my code so that it will work with anchors?

The code I'm showing works. It breaks once you add anchors to each of the images.

```
<style>
.fadein {
position:relative;


}
.fadein img {
position:absolute;
left:0;
margin:auto;
width:200px;
}
</style>

<div class="fadein">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/R7A9JXc.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/D5yaJeW.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/EUqZ1Er.png">
</div>

$(function () {
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
}, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here is your issue: `$('.fadein :first-child')`. You are selecting the first child of `.fadein` which will be a `<a />` tag if you wrap your images in anchors. You can instead just search for the first image like this:

```
$('.fadein').find('img').eq(0)...
```

Selectors can be used in many ways here, something closer to your code is:

```
$('.fadein img:eq(0)')...
```

or

```
$('.fadein img:first')
```

Documentation for jQuery selectors can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: thanks for your help. i thought it might be related to the first-child code. I tried your suggestion, but I am still getting a blank image in the transition. this is the new code with your applied update:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/9VHse/4/

Comment: @trevoray I don't have time to explain the code right now but here's a different way to do this (how I would do it): http://jsfiddle.net/9VHse/5/